# NameError at / name 'editareapage' is not defined

Tags: python, django, web, django-urls, django-manage.py

Ok so i am a noob building a basic site in django with python. I am trying to implement a new page in my site called edit area. Whenever i visit the page all i get is this...

```
NameError at /
name 'editareapage' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'editareapage' is not defined
```

My views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import datetime
def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, World!")

def mainpage(request):

    return render_to_response('mainpage.html')

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render_to_response('current_datetime.html', {'current_time':now})

def hours_ahead(request,offset):
    try:
        offset= int(offset)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()

    dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    html = "<html><body>In %s hour(s), it will be %s.</body></html>" % (offset,dt)
    return HttpResponse(html)

def editareapage(request):
    return render_to_response('editareapage.html')
```

Also it is worth noting that editareapage is the one i am trying to access.

Here is my urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from MyProj.views import hello,mainpage, current_datetime, hours_ahead
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
      (r'^hello/$', hello),
      (r'^$', mainpage),
      (r'^time/$',current_datetime),
      (r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
      (r'^editareapage/$', editareapage),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'MyProj.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^MyProj/', include('MyProj.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Hopefully  this is enough for somone to help me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import editareapage in `urls.py`

```
from MyProj.views import hello, mainpage, current_datetime, hours_ahead, editareapage
```